# session value lost after redirection in php

Tags: php, session

PHP session value lost after header redirection in php

Our code
Login.php

```
    <?php
session_start();
include('./includes/variables.php');
include_once('includes/custom-functions.php');
$fn = new custom_functions;

if (isset($_POST['btnLogin'])) {

    // get username and password
    $username = $db->escapeString($fn->xss_clean($_POST['username']));
    $password = $db->escapeString($fn->xss_clean($_POST['password']));

    // set time for session timeout
    $currentTime = time() + 25200;
    $expired = 3600;

    // create array variable to handle error
    $error = array();

    // check whether $username is empty or not
    if (empty($username)) {
        $error['username'] = "*Username should be filled.";
    }

    // check whether $password is empty or not
    if (empty($password)) {
        $error['password'] = "*Password should be filled.";
    }

    // if username and password is not empty, check in database
    if (!empty($username) && !empty($password)) {

        // change username to lowercase
        $username = strtolower($username);
        //encript password to sha256
        //$password = md5($password);

        // get data from user table
        $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username = '" . $username . "' AND password = '" . $password . "'";
        
        $db->sql($sql_query);
        /* store result */
        $res = $db->getResult();
//      print_r($res);
//      die();
        $num = $db->numRows($res);
        // Close statement object
        if ($num == 1) {
            $_SESSION['id'] = $res[0]['id'];
            $_SESSION['role'] = $res[0]['role'];
            $_SESSION['user'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['timeout'] = $currentTime + $expired;
            //print_r($_SESSION);
            //die();
            header("location: home.php");
            exit();
        } else {
            $error['failed'] = "<span class='label label-danger'>Invalid Username or Password!</span>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Home.php

```
<?php session_start();
 print_r($_SESSION);
    
   
    ?>
```

Output :
array()

We tried the following method

1. Made sure session_start(); is called before any sessions are
   being called
2. After the header redirect, end the current script using exit();
3. Made sure cookies are enabled in the browser we were using to test
   it on.
4. Made sure didn't delete or empty the session
5. Made sure file extension is .php

Comment: Are you using the session_start() in the page where you are setting `$_SESSION` array ?

Comment: yes, in the  first line of the page.

Comment: Check your log for "Headers already sent" warnings, and fix the problem that causes them.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php

Comment: we checked display errors already , it shows errors of  blank session values but not showing why session is not activated/working!

Comment: offtopic : sql query to validate username and password rough this kind of query is bas practice.

Comment: Please share your full code

Comment: code updated in question

Comment: Every things seems to ok in the code.

try to debug $_SESSION array before header redirection. When I face such issue, I always do manual debug.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include you file in which you have initialized session
For example
first file named phpcodeonly.php:

```
session_start() //put it in start
if(login success){

$_SESSION['email']= $email
}
```

your other file.php:

```
include 'phpcodeonly.php'; //on top

<h1> Welcome <?php echo  $_SESSION['email']?> </h1>
```

Comment: what have you tried. It will be easy if you have some demonstration